# Flask /w SQLAlchemy - (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked.when deployed as Azure App Service

Tags: python, azure, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, azure-web-app-service

Attempting to deploy a Flask Web Application with a Log-In form using SQLAlchemy and SQLITE3. The application behaves as expected when running locally. However, when deployed as Azure Web Service, it is not possible to access or write to the database. Doint so results in follwing error output:

```
500 Internal Server Error
2019-01-05T19:13:30.235301217Z [2019-01-05 19:13:30,198] ERROR in app: Exception on /register [POST]
2019-01-05T19:13:30.235339017Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-01-05T19:13:30.235343817Z   File 
...
2019-01-05T19:13:30.235502017Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 724, in _commit_impl
2019-01-05T19:13:30.235505417Z     self.engine.dialect.do_commit(self.connection)
2019-01-05T19:13:30.235508817Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 462, in do_commit
2019-01-05T19:13:30.235512317Z     dbapi_connection.commit()
2019-01-05T19:13:30.235624616Z sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I have troubles investigating this error as it behaves as expected locally. The Azure Web App is in a resource group not visible to others,so this can not be the source of a concurrency conflict.

models.py

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash

from app.extensions import db
from app.extensions import login


@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)
```

webapp.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import redirect
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import url_for
from flask_login import current_user
from flask_login import login_required
from flask_login import login_user
from flask_login import logout_user
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse

from app.extensions import db
from app.forms import LoginForm
from app.forms import RegistrationForm
from app.models import User

server_bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)


@server_bp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", title='Home Page')


@server_bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))

    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            error = 'Invalid username or password'
            return render_template('login.html', form=form, error=error)

        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('main.index')
        return redirect(next_page)

    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)


@server_bp.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()

    return redirect(url_for('main.index'))


@server_bp.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))

    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('main.login'))

    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)

@server_bp.route('/dynamic_chart', methods=['POST', "GET"])
def dynamicchart():
    req_data = request.get_json()

    hour1 = req_data["hour1"]
    return  hour1
```

Any idea, help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have your remote database open in some kind of database browser? I ran into a similar problem when I was examining my database with a DB Browser and trying to run queries on it at the same time.

Comment: Here is a resource for this error.. Go through this list and try to think if any of these issues could be occurring https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked

Comment: Navigate to Kudu Console and run attrib somefile.txt, and check if it includes the R (read-only) attribute. If it does, run attrib -r somefile.txt to remove it. You should also check other files in the folder in case they have the same issue (you can run attrib -r *.* to do them all at once).

Answer (score 0):

I would not use SQLite for production. I also ran into this error and changed to PostgreSQL. After that, this error never appeared anymore.